# Looking for a package for a easy WMI installation process

Tags: window, software-installation

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I wanted to test some MS Windows services via WMI client. I finally found and modified a setup process (see below), but it is very hard (recompiling core etc.).

Is there a easier way to do that? Like a pre-packaged .deb-file to install via apt-get?

```
sudo aptitude install autoconf
cd /data/tools/
wget http://www.openvas.org/download/wmi/wmi-1.3.14.tar.bz2
tar -xvf wmi-1.3.14.tar.bz2
cd wmi-1.3.14/
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo make
sudo cp Samba/source/bin/wmic /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: You should switch "sudo make" to "make". You don't need root rights to build source-code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to [compile wmi-client manually](http://techedemic.com/2014/09/17/installing-wmic-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-64-bit/) for Ubuntu 14.

Comment: @BBK..it works?

Answer (score 0):

There are Ubuntu 10.10 packages at: https://www.orvant.com/packages/

They seem to work with newer versions of Ubuntu as well (14.04 64bit tested).